# Why gcc under Windows O.S. produces a .o instead of a .lib file when compiling static libraries?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, static-libraries

I am using gcc 8.1.0 on Windows. To install it I set up Code::Blocks on my computer and updated the environment variable list by adding the path to the gcc.exe program within the installation folder of CodeBlocks. The file editor I used was the built-in editor in Visual Studio. The terminal to compile was the power shell from Visual Studio as well.

In the library development folder I have the files mul.c and mul.h. Their content is irrelevant.

To compile the library I use the command:

```
gcc -c mul.c
```

When I run it, it creates a file object mul.o and not mul.lib. I needed to use the option -o mul.lib to successfully create the desired extension file. After placing the header, the .lib file and the main.c in the same parent folder I am obvioudly able to build the executable by running.

```
gcc main.c -I./include -L/static -lmul -o my_program.exe
```

I have two questions:

- Why does gcc produces a .o if I am in a Windows environment?
- I followed a tutorial that compile the static library under Linux and it names it libmul.o, in this way the -lmul option is able to retrieve the library. But if I call my generated static library libul.lib it generates the error:

```
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-ingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmul
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Are these a normal behaviours by gcc, or is it side effect of making gcc available just by updating the Windows environmental variables list?

Thank you to the community in advance.

Comment: Should be `libmul.a` or `mul.lib`, not `libmul.lib`.

Comment: Yes, when the guy compiles under Linux with ```gcc -c mul.c``` it gets mul.o. Then he uses ``` ar rcs libmul.a ``` to generate libmul.a. But again as you see it is necessary to add the prefix  lib to succefully link the library by using the option -lmul.

Comment: Because [that's what you told GCC to do](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options): "`-c` Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link. The linking stage simply is not done. **The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file.**"

Comment: Thank you very much, since I don't have a Linux O.S. at the moment, I have a last question. Under Linux, do I need to always have a .a file to succefully link the library? I saw at [ https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/difference-between-a-and-o-912134/ ] that the only difference between a .o and a .a library is that .a can contain multiple .o objects, so I guess I would be able to link a .o object under Linux.

Comment: "I would guess that I would be able to link a `.o` object file"   Yes you can.  But not with `-l`.  You just put the object filename, including extension, on the linker command-line.

Answer (score 0):

GCC comes from the *nix world where libraries have the `.a` extension. When using GCC+MinGW this remains the case.

Shared libraries in MinGW are `.dll` files but their   libraries for linking are `.dll.a` files.

The advantage of `.a` files is that a lot of sources build out of the box on Windows with MinGW, especially when using MSYS2 shell.

If you use `-l` it will look for `.a` (or `.dll.a` for shared build) file adding the `lib` prefix and the extension automatically.

So `-lmul` will look for `libmul.a` (static, e.g. when `--static` linker flag is given) or `libmul.dll.a` (shared).

By the way, you are using quite an old GCC 8.1.0.
As I write this current version is 12.2.0. Check https://winlibs.com/ for a standalone download (instructions on how to configure in Code::Blocks are on the site) or use MSYS2's package manager `pacman`.